# How can i make one to many relation in parse using PHP

Tags: php, parse-platform

i have search alot but didn't find how to make relation in parse using php, even on parse php guide no examples are available , can you help me please

if you can show any example that would help many peoples who are looking for parse relation one to many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to make a one-to-many relation is to use Pointer.

Here is an example from [Parse's document](https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#relations-one-to-many):

> Let's say we have a game app. The game keeps track of the player's score and achievements every time she chooses to play. In Parse, we can store this data in a single Game object. If the game becomes incredibly successful, each player will store thousands of Game objects in the system. For circumstances like this, where the number of relationships can be arbitrarily large, Pointers are the best option.
>
> Suppose in this game app, we want to make sure that every Game object is associated with a Parse User. We can implement this like so:

```
$game = ParseObject::create("Game");
$game->set("createdBy", ParseUser::getCurrentUser());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) really appreciate it , can you also tell me that how to use pointers :)

Comment: Please go to the link in my answer. It explains Pointer by example. I think it's good to understand what Pointer is.